# What does "gleich" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

I am supposed to fill in the blank, but to be able to do that, I must first understand the sentence. I need help with understanding the sentence, **not** filling in the blank.

> Der Fleischhauer liegt gleich ___ der Wohnung, deshalb geht sie zu Fuß.

I translate the sentence to

> The butcher lies (?) ____ the apartment, therefor she goes by foot.

Comment: In this (!) context you may translate _gleich_ with _right_: The butcher's right .... to the apartment.

Comment: direkt, unmittelbar

Comment: Note *Fleischhauer" needs to be interpreted as "butcher's store", not the person.

Comment: For a bit of fun, fill in "vergiftet in" ;)

Comment: I think "just" instead of "right" would fit as well: _The butcher is just …… the apartment._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In this case** it is synonymous with *right* in English here:

> Der Bäcker ist gleich nebenan.
>   The bakery is right next door.

[Please do look up](http://www.dict.cc/?s=gleich) other possible meanings of *gleich* just to make sure you get the correct meaning in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The two words *liegt gleich* are referring to location. So to be literal and say lies is really not using the full terminology. *Liegt gleich* is referring to "it's right in front of" the apartment. Sometimes individual words need the assistance of other words to make the proper translation.

Comment: Etwas kann aber auch gleich hinter, neben, gegenüber von etwas liegen und es kann etwas, das im engl. männlich oder weiblich ist, sein - Deine Phrase ist also zu spezifisch.

Answer (score -1):

I’d say that *gleich* is coming from the temporal context in this case:

> When she gets out of her door, she’ll be at the butcher’s *soon*.